# Robocopy skips one directory although it looks like everything is transferred

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer, robocopy, data-transfer

I am trying to copy a large amount of data to a databox (~10 TB). I am using robocopy with this command: `robocopy <source> <destination> * /e /r:3 /w:60 /is /nfl /ndl /np /v /MT:32 or 64 /log+:logfile.txt`

It seems to be working well; however, when it completes the log looks like this:

```
       Total   Copied   Skipped   Mismatch   Failed   Extras   
Dirs:   33       33        1         0         0        0
```

I was just wondering why there is a skipped directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skipped folder in this circumstance is the last folder specified in your `<destination>` since it already exists.
For example, if you run:
`robocopy "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\FolderA" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" /e`
you'll get a skipped directory because `Desktop` already exists.
However, if you run:
`robocopy "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\FolderA" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\FolderB" /e` prior to actually making `FolderB` - robocopy will create it, and there will be no skipped directory in your summary at the bottom.